# storing shared preferences for different types of users on android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android app which has 2 login & 2 registration forms ( 2 for users and 2 for shops).The launch activity is the user's login page.
my question is how to store 2 shared preferences so that if i was already logged in as a user, it will redirect me to user's main page, and if already logged in as a shop, it will redirect me to shop's main page. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store an `Integer` for login type on user login

```
public static final int TYPE_USER = 1;
public static final int TYPE_SHOP = 2;
```

Then check for login type on launcher `Activity`

```
int type = getFromSharedPreferences();

if (type == TYPE_USER) {
   // Redirect to user's page
} else if (type == TYPE_SHOP) {
   // Redirect to shop's page
} else {
   // User not logged in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling PreferenceManager.getDefault save it in this way

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("SomeData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreference.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("key", value);//here you can put int or ...
editor.apply();
```

and you can use key or provided login info to redirect to another activity.